# Native speaker's saying for "move up and down" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction

To operate a hand pump of water one has to move the handle (lever) up and down.

As a basic learner I would say:

> Jack, **move the handle up and down** to get water.

Do native speakers use any short version for **move the handle up and down?**

Is it okay to say either: **handle or lever?**
Thank you.

Comment: We use the verb **pump** as in "pump the handle". In BrE we tend to use "handle" more often than "lever".

Answer (score 1):

Deriving from specifically this use, we use ***pump*** as a verb. It can mean up and down, it can also mean back and forth. I suppose it might be used left and right as well, though I don't recall a time it did in my experience. This is where we get expressions like *pumping iron* (moving weights up and down or back and forth so as to build up muscle) and all of the things that derive from it.

In British English, it's definitely a *handle* in that situation. A *lever* would be something used in a more basic mechanical way, and we use *lever* as a verb, but less often for something that's part of a bigger machine. I know that Americans use *lever* for more parts of machines, but I don't know if they use it for pump handles.